# What are the minimum capabilities for Application Insights to work?

Tags: windows-phone, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get Application Insights added to an existing project, which only flags the following as capabilities:

```xml
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MAP" />
```

I've added the call in my App's constructor to:

```cs
WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync();
```

And of course, I've checked the ApplicationInsights.config file to check the InstrumentationKey matches that shown on my portal.

Do I need to add additional capabilities to allow these to work, as I'm not seeing anything show up on the Azure Portal for the subscription, and I'm not seeing anything in the debug output to suggest that any diagnostics are being attempted to be sent?

Answer (score 0):

The only required capability appears to be `ID_CAP_NETWORKING`.

One other thing to watch out for; when using the UI to associate with your applciation insights it will add include a schema in the applicationInsights.config file, which stops it working.

So, instead of:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights>
  <InstrumentationKey xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

It *should* look more like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights>
  <InstrumentationKey>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Comment: interesting, where did you get your original config file?  That xmlns should have been on the `ApplicationInsights` tag, so when the tool injects the InstrumentationKey it wouldn't need it.  it seems that maybe the downstream sdk doesn't read it correctly if the xmlns is on the element itself.

Comment: Right click on the file/project choose "update Application Insights" (off the top of my head, can confirm exact wording when on dev box)

Comment: that part I know, i'm on the team that makes that part :D.  so i'm trying to figure out where the applicationinsights.config file came from originally, because that very first file on disk (however it got there) should have already had the xmlns on the top level element.

Comment: The original file failed to add when adding insights to the existing project, so was copied per steps at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started/

Comment: fantastic!  i'll make sure we get that one updated.  the only other one that had instructions like that (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135) has the correct content, where the top level tag has the top level key.